# JavaFX update UI using Platform.RunLater does not work

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I know this topic had been discussed thoroughly,
but still something is not working for me.

I have the following model (DicomModel)

```
public class DicomModel {
    private final IntegerProperty studyId;
    private final IntegerProperty seriesId;
    private final StringProperty scanTime;
    private StringProperty dicomStatus;
    private StringProperty lastMessage;
    private final List<String> messages;

    private final DicomImageType dicomImageType;
    private final File dicomFile;

    public DicomModel(DicomImageType imageType, File dicomFile, int studyId, int seriesId, String scanTime) {
        messages = new ArrayList<>();

        this.dicomImageType = imageType;
        this.dicomFile = dicomFile;
        this.studyId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(studyId);
        this.seriesId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(seriesId);
        this.scanTime = new SimpleStringProperty(scanTime);

        this.lastMessage = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.dicomStatus = new SimpleStringProperty(ExecutionStatus.Pending.getDisplayName());
    }

    /**
     * @return the studyId
     */
    public int getStudyId() {
        return studyId.get();
    }

    /**
     * @return the seriesId
     */
    public int getSeriesId() {
        return seriesId.get();
    }

    /**
     * @return the scanTime
     */
    public String getScanTime() {
        return scanTime.get();
    }

    /**
     * @return the dicomStatus
     */
    public String getDicomStatus() {
        return dicomStatus.get();
    }

    /**
     * @param dicomStatus the dicomStatus to set
     */
    public void setDicomStatus(ExecutionStatus dicomStatus) {
        this.dicomStatus.set(dicomStatus.getDisplayName());
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastMessage
     */
    public String getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage.get();
    }

    /**
     * @return the messages
     */
    public List<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    /**
     * Add a new message to the DICOM model.
     * The new message will be inserted to the list of {@link DicomModel} messages,
     * and be visible as latest message received. 
     * @param newDicomSendResponse The retrieved DICOM message from DICOM send module. 
     */
    public void addMessage(String newDicomSendResponse){
        messages.add(newDicomSendResponse);
        this.lastMessage.set(newDicomSendResponse);
    }

    /**
     * @return the dicomImageType
     */
    public DicomImageType getDicomImageType() {
        return dicomImageType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dicomFile
     */
    public File getDicomFile() {
        return dicomFile;
    }
}
```

Here is my fxml TableView column defenition:

```xml
<TableView fx:id="_tvDicomSend" prefWidth="${_queueBox.width}">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn text="Study" prefWidth="120">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="studyId" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Series" prefWidth="120">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="seriesId" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Scan time" prefWidth="120">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="scanTime" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Status" prefWidth="70">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="dicomStatus" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Last message" prefWidth="400">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="lastMessage" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

And here is how I populate data.
Here is the Callable which  is used inside an ExecutorService (In handleResponse method)

```
class executorThread implements Callable<Boolean>, DicomResponseListener{
    private final DicomModel dicom;

    public executorThread(DicomModel dicom) {
        dicomComm.addListener(this);
        this.dicom = dicom;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        dicom.setDicomStatus(ExecutionStatus.Running);
        sendDicom(dicom.getDicomImageType(), dicom.getDicomFile());

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResponse(DicomResponseType responseType, String responseMessage) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> dicom.addMessage(responseMessage));
        //dicomSendController.refreshUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleDicomCompletion(DicomReturnCode returnCode) {
        dicom.setDicomStatus(ExecutionStatus.Completed);
        //dicomSendController.refreshUI();
        dicomComm.removeListener(this);
    }
}
```

Now a small overview:
This executor resides in a DicomSendManager which holds a queue of DicomModel objects.
When I insert a new object to the queue, I insert it aswell to an ObservableList in the DicomSendController.
Here is a code snippet of this method:

```
/**
 * Add a new DICOM image to the DICOMs list, the controller, and the execution queue
 * @param newDicom {@link DicomModel} to add
 */
private void addNewDicom(DicomModel newDicom){
    // Add the new DICOM to the execution list
    dicomImages.add(newDicom);
    // Add the new DICOM to the UI Controller
    dicomSendController.addDicomImage(newDicom);
    // Submit the DICOM to execution queue
    executor.submit(new executorThread(newDicom));
}
```

Their defenitions:

- `List<DicomModel> dicomImages = new ArrayList<DicomModel>();`
- `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`
- `ObservableList<DicomModel> dicomSendQueue = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` - In the UI Controller

**Now for the problem.**
Even though the `Platform.RunLater()` insert the new messages to the DicomModel, it does not update the UI.
Side note: I know this method works because When I put in it a small console print message, it does print it.

The only UI update I get is:

- If a new DicomModel is inserted to the ObservableList then it updates the values of the old DicomModel object
- If I manually invoke `_tvDicomSend.Refresh()` (force refresh of the TableView).

What am I missing here?
Is there anything wrong with my concept?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't go through the entire code, but it seems you are missing the property getters ('public IntegerProperty studyIdProperty()' etc.), so the `PropertyValueFactory` is forced to use the getters and setters, thus it has no way of registering a change listener.

Comment: @sillyfly That does not help. Tried various options: changing my getters and setter to return the property values, adding additional getter and setters with the method name as you've suggested: getStudyIdProperty(), and even changing the property fields to public. Nothing changed

Comment: @nafarkash None of the things you describe match the actual [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) that is expected by the `PropertyValueFactory` which you are using for the cell value factories on the table columns. The [documentation for `PropertyValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) explicitly describes the methods that it is going to look for in the model. Try that approach, and if it doesn't work, edit your code to show that attempt.

Comment: @James_D exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Can't mark this as an answer for some reason though..

Comment: Because it's not an answer, it's just a comment. @sillyfly should provide the answer since the first comment correctly identifies the problem and provides the solution. I will add an answer if one doesn't appear in a few hours.